# Importing users from text file to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, import

My table name is generated it has these columns: `(id, username, password)` - nothing fancy :)

My users.text have this:

> ```
> expert1001 01995056
> expert1002 58381484
> expert1003 03154500
> expert1004 45885204
> expert1005 24750107
> expert1006 14096885
> expert1007 81250562
> expert1008 00910766
> expert1009 99830724
> ```

I'm trying to export those generated users to my db but I'm trying to do a check if the user already exists; if so I move on to the next one but I'm getting this error and I don't see it.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

(PHP version 5.3.5)

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "1234";
$db = "users";
$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Unable to connect!");
mysql_select_db($db) or die ("Unable to select database!"); 
$file = file('users.text'); # read file into array
$count = count($file);
if($count > 0) # file is not empty
{
    $milestone_query ="INSERT into `generated`(`username`, `password`) values";
    $i = 1;
    foreach($file as $row)
    {
$milestone = explode(' ',$row);
$requete ="SELECT * FROM `lines` WHERE `username`='$milestone[0]'";
$queryset=mysql_query($requete);
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryset)){
$bood = "".$row2['username']."";
$us=$milestone[0];
if ($us == $bood )
{
  $i++; 
}  else {
$milestone_query .= "('$milestone[0]',  '$milestone[1]')"; 
$milestone_query .= $i < $count ? ',':'';
$i++; 
}
}
}
if ($milestone_query != NULL ){

mysql_query($milestone_query) or die(mysql_error());

}else{
die();
}
}
echo "Done!";
?>
```

Comment: Can you dump the final query?

Comment: "INSERT into `generated`(`username`, `password`) values('expert11001',  '01995056\n'),('expert11001',  '01995056\n'),('expert11001',  '01995056\n'),('expert11001',  '01995056\n'),('expert11001',  '01995056\n'),('expert11001',  '01995056\n'),('expert11001',  '01995056\n'),('expert11001',  '01995056\n'),('expert11001',  '01995056\n')"

Comment: The indentation is rather erratic in this code. This makes it harder for us to read, but it'll make it harder for you to debug too. If you can fix it in your code, and here, that is often helpful.

Comment: Are you sure it is the `INSERT` it is crashing on, and not the `SELECT`?

Comment: yes thats what make me crazy the insert seem ok but it dos nothing its just getting the error

Answer (score 0):

i made some changers and its seems to work now but i still have one probleme is , at the end of the query i cant find out how to trim it before submiting the query

here is the code

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "123456";
$db = "generated";
$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Unable to connect!");
mysql_select_db($db) or die ("Unable to select database!"); 
$file = file('users.text'); # read file into array
$count= count($file);
if($count > 0) # file is not empty
{
    $milestone_query ="INSERT into `users`(`username`, `password`) values";
    $i = 1;
    foreach($file as $row)
    {
        $row = str_replace("\n", '', $row);
        $milestone = explode(' ',$row);
        $us= $milestone[0];
$requete ="SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$us'";
$queryset=mysql_query($requete);
$row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryset); 
$bood = $row2['username'];
if ($us == $bood)
{
  $i++;

}  else{
        $milestone_query .= "('$milestone[0]', '$milestone[1]')";
        $milestone_query .= $i < $count ? ',':'';

}

}
mysql_query($milestone_query) or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

here is the query result

> "INSERT into `users`(`username`, `password`) values('aspireupp7p',
>   '97025407'),('artre1r7pp', '40138199'),('asuiozy4p',
>   '44896449'),('asuytrdiop', '36582797'),"

u see at the end i have this **,**  can you guys help me with that thank you

Comment: any one can chk this plz ?

Answer (score 0):

I have cleaned up the code a little.. Good luck!

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "123456";
$db = "generated";

$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Unable to connect!");
mysql_select_db($db) or die ("Unable to select database!");

$users = file('users.text'); # read file into array
if ($count = count($users)) # file is not empty
{

    $milestone_query = "INSERT into `users`(`username`, `password`) values";
    $milestone_query_count = strlen($milestone_query);

    foreach ($users as $i => $user) {
        $userInfo = explode(' ',trim($user));
        $username = current($userInfo);
        $password = next($userInfo);

        $requete = "SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `username` ='{$username}'";
        if(!$result =boolval(mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($requete)))){
            var_dump($username." added!");
            $milestone_query .= "('$username', '$password'),";
        }

    }

    $milestone_query = trim($milestone_query, ",");

    if(strlen($milestone_query) !== 50){
        mysql_query($milestone_query) or die(mysql_error());
        var_dump("finished!");
    }else{
        var_dump("No new users!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Please use answers for complete answers only. If you think the question can be improved by editing it, just propose an edit.

Comment: @BaummitAugen sorry, i thought I was answering his question. have you seen his comment?  he asked for someone to check his code.

Comment: Yes, then you did some "cleanup" without telling him what you did and why. Now he can copy paste your code and use it (assuming it is correct), but what did he learn from it? You did not even tell him where his syntax error came from. And improving the (admittedly quite poor) formatting alone should have been an edit (unless the formatting is the actual problem, then state that in your answer).